# Sorting a vector of structs c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a struct where data is defined as:

```
typedef struct contacts 
{
    string name;
    string nickName;
    string phoneNumber;
    string carrier;
    string address;
    //callDetails callDetails;

} contactDetails;

vector <contactDetails> proContactFile;
```

I have like 10 -20 fields of information inside the vector.
I need to bubble sort the `name`(Alphabetically),and display other respective data infront of name.(As an example after sorting a names i want to display the respective `nickname , phone number ,carrier` and `address` infront of that sorted name.) Is there a  simple way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learning about "**custom comparators**" will solve your problem. Here is one of the ways to achieve the desired result. I am using `cmp` as a custom comparator. Notice that it is passed while calling `sort()`.

This way is useful if you need to sort on basis of something else tomorrow, say `phoneNumber`. The only change you would need is adding or updating a comparator function to `return c1.phoneNumber < c2.phoneNumber;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef struct contacts
{
    string name;
    string nickName;
    string phoneNumber;
    string carrier;
    string address;
    //callDetails callDetails;
} contactDetails;

//sort based on name
bool cmp (const contacts& c1, const contacts& c2) {
    return c1.name < c2.name;
}

void print(vector <contactDetails> proContactFile) {
    for (auto s : proContactFile) {
        cout << s.name << " " << s.nickName << " " << s.phoneNumber << " " << s.carrier << " " << s.address << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector <contactDetails> proContactFile;

    proContactFile.push_back({"name1","nickName1","phone1","carrier1", "address1"});
    proContactFile.push_back({ "ame1","ickName1","hone1","arrier1", "ddress1" });
    proContactFile.push_back({ "me1","ckName1","one1","rrier1", "dress1" });
    proContactFile.push_back({ "e1","kName1","ne1","rier1", "ress1" });

    sort(proContactFile.begin(), proContactFile.end(), cmp);
    print(proContactFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the standard template library?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> s = {4, 7, 6, 3, 9, 2, 1, 0, 8, 3}; ; 
 
    // sort using the default operator<
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
}
```

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

You just need to define your compare operator '<' for your type.

Comment: Yeah i tried something like that.But it was not working for me..I mean with that i could  only sort the names..I can't print other respective data infront of the name.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Sort the vector by name to get a sorted vector and then you can print whatever you what from the struct fields contained in the sorted vector in another loop. What am I missing?

Comment: I mean I can sort and print  only the  names alphabetically. But here I want to print relevant `nick name,carrier, phone num` and `address` infront of sorted name.So basically what i'm doing in my project is i'm reading a file into a vector and then sorting.

Comment: "You just need to define your compare operator '<' for your type." why don't you show how to do this with OP's struct?